# How can I identify if my LCD screen has an LED backlight?

Tags: display, lcd, led

MY new XPS 15s screen broke so i had it replaced. However i'm having doubts that instead of my normal LED backlit screen I have been given an traditionally backlit screen.

How do I find out ?

Comment: You are aware that, for all intents and purposes, all LED screens are LCDs that use LEDs for the backlight, right?

Answer (score 1):

**updated**

LED-backlit screens and "traditional" backlit screens are difficult to distinguish, especially externally.

The easiest option isn't guaranteed, but you can look for stickers or model# information indicating the backlight type.  In your case, where the backlight may have been altered, this won't be useful.

Internally the two have some differences.  Firstly, if you can see the backlight itself it may be easy to tell if it is a more traditional bulb.  If not, I found the following information:

[SparePartsWarehouse - How to Identify an LED LCD Screen](http://www.sparepartswarehouse.com/blog/post/how-to-identify-an-led-lcd-screen.aspx)

> The first thing you will notice about LED backlit displays is that
>   they do not require an inverter. The inverter is usually a long
>   rectangular circuit board located at the bottom of the display. If the
>   inverter is not present, the laptop most likely uses LED backlights.

Comment: The user probably asked how to tell the difference between an LED and a non-LED backlit screen. If you can answer that, +1.

Comment: ahh!  good point Daniel, that interpretation didn't occur to me